# elasticsearch angular js error -1

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I want show elastic search data on web page that using angular js

I run this code file but error message occurred like "error:-1".

I curious what some part of this file occurred error.

if anyone answers to me I really appreciate

I have attached an execution screen.

thank you.

Execution screen:

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="QueryController"></div>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/elasticsearch-browser/elasticsearch.angular.js"></script>

<script>


    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['elasticsearch']);

    // Create the es service from the esFactory


    myApp.service('es', function (esFactory) {
        return esFactory({ host: "http://localhost:9200"});
    });

    myApp.controller('ServerHealthController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

        es.cluster.health(function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                $scope.data = err.message;

            } else {
                $scope.data = resp;

            }
        });
    });

    // We define an Angular controller that returns query results,
    // Inputs: $scope and the 'es' service

    myApp.controller('QueryController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

// search for documents
        es.search({

            index: 'epowersyst',
            type: 'logs',
            body: {
              query:
                {
                  match_all : {} }
                }

        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.hits = response;
            console.log($scope.hits)

        }).catch(function (err) {
          if (err.status === 404) {
            alert("error 404" );

          } else {
            alert("error : " + err.status );

          }
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your request is not sent or aborted, while accessing `http://localhost:9200`, so you get `response code -1`, read doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: thank you! i checked your link but i don't understand 
can you inform to me how i fix this code??

Comment: is your backend running at `http://localhost:9200`? if not then make sure it is running and I hope you making some `http` call in your factory.

Comment: I think you can get more information on the error by changing line 63 from err.status to err. It's likely there's a field like data or message which is more verbose

Comment: I corrected err.status to error and this error message appeared :  unknown error :: {"path":"/epowersyst/logs/_search","query":{},"body":"{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}","statusCode":-1,"response":null}